# How to increase available PermGen space for forked tests?

Tags: sbt

This is for sbt 0.13.5.

I keep getting `Out of PermGen space` errors upon running my tests. I created the following in my `.bashrc`:

```
export SBT_OPTS="-Xmx2536M -XX:MaxPermSize=4000M"
```

but it makes no difference.

I'm using

```
fork in Test := true
```

Is there a different setting for the fork? How do I figure out how much I'm actually using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the official documentation of sbt in [Forked JVM options](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Forking.html#Forked+JVM+options):

> To specify options to be provided to the forked JVM, set `javaOptions`.

Use `javaOptions` scoped to `Test` configuration to have your tests be running with non-default settings as follows:

```
javaOptions in Test += "-Xmx8G"
```

To learn about the current values use `inspect`:

```
> show test:javaOptions
[info] List(-Xmx8G)
```

I don't know how to know the default values when `javaOptions` is not set explicitly.